# I'm trying to install skytools in order to migrate a DB to an Amazon RDS, but I'm getting an error

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services

Setup Details:
1x EC2 running Ubuntu 14.04 with Postgres 9.3,
1x RDS running Postgres 9.3

I am trying to move a postgres database that I have on an EC2 onto an RDS. I am using Londiste, which is [recommended by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/rds-postgres-read-replicas/) for migrating databases with minimal downtime. Specifically, I am using Londiste/Skytools 2.1.13, because Londiste3 requires superuser privileges on both systems.

I have tried installing Skytools both via the zip from their website and via apt-get (both 2.1.13). I have installed what I believe to be all of the dependencies: postgres,libpq-dev, postgresql-server-dev-9.3, pip, and psycopg2.

Regardless, whenever I try to use any skytools commands, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/pgqadm.py", line 9, in 
>   from pgq.ticker import SmartTicker   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pgq/**init**.py", line 6, in
>
> import pgq.consumer   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pgq/consumer.py", line 6, 
>   in 
>       from pgq.baseconsumer import BaseConsumer, BaseBatchWalker   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pgq/baseconsumer.py", line 75,
>
> in 
>       class BaseConsumer(skytools.DBScript):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skytools/apipkg.py", line 114,
>
> in __makeattr
>       result = importobj(modpath, attrname)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skytools/apipkg.py", line 37,
>
> in importobj
>       module = **import**(modpath, None, None, ['**doc**'])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/skytools/scripting.py", line
>   23,
>
> in 
>       default_skylog = skytools.installer_config.skylog
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'skylog'

Am I missing a dependency? (Skylog seems to be a part of skytools, so I've concluded it's not that.) Has anyone else hit this issue? (There don't seem to be any google results with this error.) Thanks!

Comment: I've also hit this issues. Did you solve it already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr:

make sure you're running `pgqadm.py` that is in your local `skytools-2.x.y` installation directory, eg: `./python/pgqadm.py ticker.ini install`

This can be a problem if you have previously installed Skytools 3.x, which may come up first in your `PATH`.

#### Background

I just ran into this same issue. I have the same use case (migrating pg->rds), and followed the same recommendation from the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html).

I had initially installed Skytools 3.x before noticing that it requires superuser privileges on the would-be replica. `which pgqadm.py` returns `/usr/bin/pgqadm.py`, which is an artifact of my abandoned Skytools 3.x installation.

I became suspicious of a version conflict when I went to the Skytools source repository looking for instances of `skylog`. The first result was here:
https://github.com/pgq/skytools-legacy/blob/11afc5210a92d4a2ccf701e4f92138488c31a3cb/python/skytools/installer_config.py.in

However, I realized that this repository is now tracking the latest 3.x release. I switched to the apparent 2.1.x branch, and `skylog` was nowhere to be found, as expected:

https://github.com/pgq/skytools-legacy/blob/skytools_2_1_stable/python/skytools/installer_config.py.in

Fully-qualifying the path to `pgqadm.py` resolves this issue in this case.